# Prevent sizeForItemAt from using the wrong cell size because of reuse for dynamic collectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I used auto layout to dynamically calculate the size of the collectionView cell. Some cells are using the dimensions from the reused cells when they first scrolled to view port. As I continue to scroll the collectionView, they will be set to the correct value.

In my `sizeForItemAt`, I have the following:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if let cachedSize = cachedHeightForIndexPath[indexPath] {
            return cachedSize
        }

        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
            cell.setNeedsLayout()
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            let size = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
            cachedHeightForIndexPath[indexPath] = size
            print("value is \(size) for indexpath: \(indexPath)")
            return size
        }
        return CGSize(width: ScreenSize.width, height: 0.0)
    }
```

I have a three sessions, with the first section all cell's height theoretically equals to 88, and all the other sections all cell's height equals to 104.

Originally, only the first section is visible. From the console, I can see the height of the cell is set to 88.0 as expected. As I scroll to the remaining sections(the first section will be invisible and the cells will be reused), some cells from second section and third section are using the value 88.0 as the height of the cells when first scrolled to view port instead of 104. As I continue to scroll, the wrong sized cell will be using 104 as the dimension. How do we force all the cells to recalculate the height and don't use the height from old cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but when you measure the cell by its internal constraints by calling `systemLayoutSizeFitting`, instead of calling `systemLayoutSizeFitting` on an *existing* cell (`collectionView.cellForItem`), you need to arm yourself with a *model* cell that you configure the same as `cellForItem` would configure it and measure *that*.

Here's how I do it (remarkably similar to what you have, with that one difference; also, I store the size in the model):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let memosize = self.sections[indexPath.section].itemData[indexPath.row].size
    if memosize != .zero {
        return memosize
    }
    self.configure(self.modelCell, forIndexPath:indexPath) // in common with cellForItem
    var sz = self.modelCell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
    sz.width = ceil(sz.width); sz.height = ceil(sz.height)
    self.sections[indexPath.section].itemData[indexPath.row].size = sz // memoize
    return sz
}
```

Comment: I see, but how would you initialize a modelCell since the model cell is not the actual cell?

Comment: There is no way to get the correct dimension for the reused cell even after all the data is populated?

Comment: How do you know that data is already populated? You should make no assumptions whatever about _when_ `sizeForItem` will be called for any particular cell / item. The assumptions you are already making are the reason you are having trouble! I'm telling you how to stop making them.

Comment: To create a model cell, do you have to duplicate all the view set up logic like what's in the real cell in order to correctly config it? Like it's a view but it's just not reusable.